# How to destroy an array of custom components

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a destroy procedure for a custom component '`TCARD`'. Then  during runtime i create an array

```
Cards: array[1..20] of TCards
```

then i do some things...
and at end of procedure i would like to destroy all the TCards in the array. How do i do this or do i have to do each one at a time like so.

```
cards[1].destroy;
cards[2].destroy;
....
cards[20].destroy;
```

Comment: Stop using arrays for objects and use TObjectList<T>. Object destruction is managed by the list.

Comment: have not used TobjectList<i> will look into it.. but if i use that then i can do a TObjectlist.destroy ?

Comment: TObjectList<T> is what you need. But have you never heard of a for loop? Seriously, if you can't see that solution you need to go back to basics a little.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i have but was hopeing there was an Array.destroy or something like so. and I am still on basics.. I find when teaching everything your self you dont learn basics - advance in that order.. i find starting a project and going threw it teaches me better. and to do this you usually use some basic up to some advance.. but maybe i am wrong :D

Comment: Use some higher level containers where you can then so that you shield your self from the nitty gritty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `TObjectList<T>`, this will be done for you, all you need to do is destroy the list.

```
Uses
  Generics.Collections,
...

// define your list
Cards: TObjectList<TCard>;

...

// create list
Cards := TObjectList<TCard>.Create;
try
 // Create and add your card objects
 ACard := TCard.Create;
 Cards.Add(ACard);
 // do something with Cards
 ...
 // destroy cards - this will automatically free the objects owned by the list
finally
 Cards.Free;
end;
```

As an added bonus you can make your own custom object and add Card related functions to it.

```
type
  TMyCardList = class(TObjectList<TCard>)
  public
   // add needed behaviours
   function FindHighestCardBySuit(ASuit : TSuit) : TCard;
   procedure Shuffle;
   // etc ...
  end;
```

If for some reason you don't want to use `TObjectList`, you can free the objects with a simple loop:

```
procedure FreeCards(Cards : TCards);

var
  Card : TCard;

begin
 For Card in Cards do
  Card.Free;
end;
```

Comment: the do somethng with cards.  currently i have for example `cards[i].Cname := adoquery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString;`  I assume i can still do something like this sorry i have not searched yet, just still changeing code

Comment: Yes you can loop them like a normal array :)

Comment: pushing it i know,  but once the objects are in the list. and i edit the objects in the list. I then have to make the orginal objects = the items in the list correct? or does the objects in the list directly affect the orginal objects?  if this should be another question i understand

Comment: The object stands on its own, it doesn't know it is in a list or an array. The objectlist is just a container.

Comment: for example :  `MyObject := MyList[i]; MyObject.field := 1;` is the same as `MyList[i].field := 1`. It is the same object, understand?

Comment: yea i deleted the comment due to finding i had the cards[z].destroy inside wrong loop :(

Comment: Ok. Just one hint, me and hundreds of other developers usually use `Free` instead of `Destroy`. It's safer to use `Free` because it first checks if the object on which you're calling it is not `nil` and then calls `Destroy` inside. Using directly `Destroy` isn't wrong anyhow if you know the object on which you call it is not `nil`, just commonly used and safer is `Free`.